# Order dataframe based on inherent values within column

Tags: r, sorting, dplyr

I would like to capture inherent values of within the dataframe and then order the columns and rows from descending to ascending based on the number of events in each column and row.

Sample Data

```
 #A tibble: 26 x 9
   sample_id Gene_A Gene_B Gene_C Gene_D Gene_E Gene_F Gene_G Gene_H
   <fct>      <int>  <int>  <int>  <int>  <int>  <int>  <int>  <int>
 1 A             -1      0      0      0     -1      0      0     -1
 2 B              1      0     -1      1     -1     -1     -1      0
 3 C              1      0     -1      0      1      0      0     -1
 4 D             -1      0      0     -1      1      1     -1      1
 5 E              1      1      1      1     -1      1     -1      0
 6 F             -1     -1      1      1      1     -1      0      0
 7 G              0      0     -1     -1      0     -1      0     -1
 8 H              1      1      1      0      1     -1     -1      0
 9 I              0     -1     -1     -1      0     -1      0      1
10 J             -1      0      0      1     -1     -1      0      1
# ... with 16 more rows
```

The final result I am going for is a table that is ordered on the following hierarchy:

- based on number of Genes with most events to least events

  - then, based on the number of events per sample_id from most events to least events.

Here is the sample output:

```
# A tibble: 26 x 9
   sample_id Gene_B Gene_G Gene_H Gene_A Gene_C Gene_D Gene_F Gene_E
 * <chr>      <int>  <int>  <int>  <int>  <int>  <int>  <int>  <int>
 1 A              0      0     -1     -1      0      0      0     -1
 2 U              0     -1      0      0      0     -1      0      1
 3 C              0      0     -1      1     -1      0      0      1
 4 G              0      0     -1      0     -1     -1     -1      0
 5 W              0     -1      1      1      0      1      0      0
 6 Y              0      0      1      1      0      1      1      0
 7 I             -1      0      1      0     -1     -1     -1      0
 8 J              0      0      1     -1      0      1     -1     -1
 9 O              0      1      0      0      1     -1      1      1
10 P              1     -1     -1      0     -1      0      0     -1
# ... with 16 more rows
```

My first though was to take absolute sum and add a column with total for each sample, take absolute sum and add a row with total for each column and then use order.

Generating Sample Data

```
dummy.tb <- tibble (sample_id = (sample (1:30,30)), Gene_A = (sample
(-1:1,30, replace = T)), Gene_B = (sample (-1:1,30, replace = T)))

dummy1.tb <- tibble (Gene_C = (sample (-1:1,30, replace = T)), Gene_D
= (sample (-1:1,30, replace = T)), Gene_E = (sample (-1:1,30, replace = T)))

dummy2.tb <- tibble (Gene_F = (sample (-1:1,30, replace = T)), Gene_G
= (sample (-1:1,30, replace = T)), Gene_H = (sample (-1:1,30, replace = T)))

dummy.tb <- cbind.data.frame(dummy.tb, dummy1.tb, dummy2.tb)

dummy.genes <- c ("Gene_A", "Gene_B", "Gene_C", "Gene_D", "Gene_E",
"Gene_F", "Gene_G", "Gene_H")

dummy.total <- as.data.frame (dummy.total)
```

Add Col_Total and Column Sums

```
dummy.total <- dummy.tb %>% bind_rows(summarise_all(., funs(if(is.numeric(.)) sum(abs(.)) else "Col_Total")))

dummy.total <- as.data.frame (dummy.total)
```

sort for column

```
dummy.total <- dummy.total [,order(dummy.total[nrow(dummy.total),], decreasing = FALSE)]
```

delete Col_Total row

```
dummy.total <- dummy.total %>% filter (!sample_id == "Col_Total")

dummy.total <- as.data.frame (dummy.total)
```

Add Row Totals and Row Sums

```
dummy.total <- dummy.total %>% mutate (Row_Total = rowSums (abs((select (., one_of(dummy.genes))))))

dummy.total <- as.data.frame (dummy.total)
```

sort for row

```
dummy.total <- dummy.total [order (dummy.total [,ncol(dummy.total)], decreasing = FALSE),]
```

delete Row_Total column

```
dummy.total <- dummy.total %>% select (-Row_Total)
```

Reorder with sample_id

```
dummy.total <- dummy.total %>% select (sample_id, everything())

dummy.total <- as.tibble(dummy.total)
```

This code does works and gives the desired output but it seems too verbose with lot of changes in structures along the way. Any suggestions using tidyverse or other methods? I tried using `arrange ()` instead of order for ordering the columns based on values on `Col_Total` but did not seem to work.

Note: It is per event, not just a straight forward sum so absolute values are included to calculate the number of events.

Comment: Please correct the quotes.  It is giving errors

Comment: Changed the quotes for dummy.genes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this problem `matrix` is a better fit as you handle homogeneous (numeric) data. If you assign column names and `sample_id` to `dimnames` of `matrix` you will be able to preserve the column and row identifiers after sorting.

I recommend you to use `set.seed` so your examples will be reproducible and it will be possible to validate the answer with the desired output.

Please see as below:

```
set.seed(123)
n <- 30
m <- 9
mat <- matrix(
  sample(-1:1, n * m, replace = TRUE), 
  nrow = n,   
  dimnames = list(1:n, paste("Gene", LETTERS[1:m], sep = "_"))
)
foo <- mat[, order(colSums(abs(mat)))]
bar <- foo[order(rowSums(abs(foo))), ]
head(bar)
```

Output:

```
   Gene_F Gene_D Gene_I Gene_G Gene_C Gene_A Gene_H Gene_B Gene_E
18     -1      0      0      0      0     -1      0      0      1
15      0      0      0      1      0     -1     -1     -1      0
27      0      0      0      0      1      0     -1     -1     -1
1       1     -1      0      1      0     -1      0      1      0
3       0      0     -1      1      0      0     -1      1     -1
6       0     -1      1      0      0     -1      1      0      1
```